# Android sdk in Eclipse

Tags: android

I installed the Android sdk and Eclipse Indigo on windows 64 bit. But when i started Eclipse to start a new project, i could not see Android Project under Android folder.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the ADT plugin.
See this:

Eclipse ADT

> http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Installing the Eclipse Plugin

> http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: @user1532099: Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem. stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: i used all that but it displayed Android Application Project